# Easyresponsivetab is not working with MVC5

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-5

Working site - http://184.106.114.93/origolo/website/help.html
Same HTML when integrated with MVC5 throws an error - **"TypeError:   $(...).easyResponsiveTabs is not a function"

MVC5 integrated - http://184.106.114.93/Origolo/Home/help**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The issue says `$(...).easyResponsiveTabs is not a function`, it's because in the http://184.106.114.93/Origolo/Home/help can not find the files:

```
<script src="/Origolo/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Origolo/js/easyResponsiveTabs.js"></script>
```

make sure it's pointing to the right place, because the browser says error 404 not found for tha files.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.
We are referring to right path, issue still persists :(

Comment: have you fixed the issue? @NaveenSR